# how to pickup record in oracle sql 10g when the time difference is 5 minutes

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

I have table which have column date_col .
There is job which fetch data from this table every 5 minute

I want to pick up record which have changed in last 5 minute

Similarity for another table it is 1 hour

How can I do that?

Comment: Does the date_col updated after every update or it's just used while insertion?

Comment: you can also use **SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL(5, 'Minute')** or **SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'Hour')** as your condition

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple in oracle with the help of function `sysdate`.
this function returns the current date value from DB server.

so you can use something like -

```
 select * 
  from <your-table> 
  where date_col > sysdate - ((5/24)/60)
```

similarly for one hour -- `sysdate - (1/24)`

hope this helps you in your task.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date_col hold the audit of last changed records

```
select * from table1 where date_col between  sysdate-(5/(24*60)) and sysdate
```

Comment: I also thought of using `between` in sql but thinking of upper limit (`sysdate`)  changed my mind to use just `>` comparison instead.

Well this is also a approach to do this..

Answer (score 0):

We can do basic arithmetic with Oracle dates. So to find datetimes of five minutes' ago we can do this: `where date_col >= sysdate - (5/(24*60))`.

A slightly more expressive approach uses the interval datatype. For ranges of days to seconds there is the TO_DSINTERVAL() function:  `where date_col >= sysdate - to_ds_interval('0 0:5:0')`. An hour interval would be  `where date_col >= sysdate - to_ds_interval('0 1:0:0')`.

---

Your approach proposes using sysdate. This is fine as a first step but perhaps not resilient enough for a real application. What happens if your job runs for more than five minutes? Or dies and has to be restarted? A more robust solution would be to log job start times and pick up records which have been touched since the previous job ran.